# Independence of composite random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ have probability density of $f_X=xe^{-x}dx$ on $\mathbb{R}^+$ and $U$ the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ independent of $X$. Define $Y_1=UX$ and $Y_2=(1-U)X$. The goal is now to show that $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent. The proof I'm looking at works as follows:

First, considering the distribution of $(Y_1,Y_2)$ using expected value $E(f(UX,(1-U)X))=\int_0^1 \int_0^\infty xe^{-x}f(ux,f((1-u)x))dxdu = \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty f(s,t)e^{-(t+s)}dsdt$.

Then, the proof says that since we can represent the law of $(Y_1,Y_2)$ as product of the law of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$, they're independent.

But how can we do this? How can we know that $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ have laws $e^{-t}dt$, $e^{-s}ds$ respectively?

Comment: Is the function $f$ over which you take the expected value the density or is it a random function?

Comment: It's any bounded function, using the proposition that $E(f(X))=\int_\Omega f(x)dP_x$

Comment: I think the argument goes approximately as follows:

Comment: they conclude that $$E(g(Y_1,Y_2)) = \int g(y_1,y_2)\cdot f(y_1,y_2)\,\mathrm{d} (y_1,y_2). $$ Hence the distribution function of $(Y_1,Y_2)$ equals $e^{-y_1 - y_2}$. This is not that trivial but it is a known result that if it holds for all bounded $g$. This then factorizes, ie you can write it as a function depending on $y_1$ and one depending on $y_2$. Thus $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent.

Comment: Hmm, I see. But is it enough to just note that we can factorize this function in this way? Couldn't it be that the probability functions of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are others, using another change of variabels for example?

Comment: Your question is about independence but you forgot to say that $X$ and$ U$ are independent. The result is false as stated.

Comment: @GottlobtFrege, yes it should be enough. I don't have a reference at the moment but I think you should be able to find one, probably in almost every mathematical probability book. Kavi, yeah you re right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are jointly distributed as independent exponentials. The easiest way to see this is probably to just do a change of variables. We have $$ X = Y_1+Y_2\\U = \frac{Y_1}{Y_1+Y_2},$$ giving a Jacobian of $\frac{1}{y_1+y_2}.$ Then we have $$ f_{Y_1,Y_2}(y_1,y_2) = \frac{1}{y_1+y_2}f_{X,U}\left(y_1+y_2, \frac{y_1}{y_1+y_2}\right) = \frac{1}{y_1+y_2}(y_1+y_2) e^{-(y_1+y_2)}= e^{-(y_1+y_2)}.$$

This solves the problem, but I assume the theorem you're trying to use is that $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent if and only if $$ E(g_1(Y_1)g_2(Y_2)) = E(g_1(Y_1))E(g_2(Y_2))$$ for all (sufficiently well behaved) functions $g_1$ and $g_2.$ So to apply your integral to this, you need to take $f(x,y) = g_1(x)g_2(y),$ and you have $$ E(g_1(Y_1)g_2(Y_2)) \\= \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty g_1(s)g_2(t) e^{-(s+t)}dsdt \\= \left(\int_0^\infty g_1(s) e^{-s}ds\right)\left(\int_0^\infty g_2(t) e^{-t}dt\right) \\= E(g_1(Y_1))E(g_2(Y_2))$$ since $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are both exponentially distributed. Of course using our previous results is overkill here since they already show independence. However, perhaps the intention was to show that $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are marginally exponential, through some other method, for instance you can do the integral $$ P(Y_1\le y ) = P(X\le y/U) = \int_0^1 du\int_0^{y/u} xe^{-x} dx = 1-e^{-y},$$ which works out, but I find no less burdensome than the change of variables above.

Comment: Thank you very much! You said "Of course using our previous results is overkill here since they already show independence. ", where then is the first time we proved independence?

Comment: @GottlobtFrege By 'previous results' I meant the change of variables where I derived $f_{Y_1,Y_2}(y_1,y_2)=e^{-y_1}e^{-y_2}.$ This shows both independence and the fact that the marginal distributions are exponential.